# How would one create a proper polymorphic Functor instance failing on unsafeVacuous?

Tags: haskell, functor, gadt, bottom-type

When discussing `Void` on Haskell Libraries mailing list, there was [this remark](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-July/020147.html):

> Back in the day it used to be implemented by an `unsafeCoerce` at the behest
>   of Conor McBride who didn't want to pay for traversing the whole `Functor`
>   and replacing its contents, when the types tell us that it shouldn't have
>   any. This is correct if applied to a proper Functor, but subvertible in the
>   presence of GADTs.

The documentation for [`unsafeVacuous`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/void/0.6.1/doc/html/Data-Void-Unsafe.html) also says:

> If `Void` is uninhabited than any `Functor` that holds only values of the type `Void` is holding no values.
>
> This is only safe for **valid functors** that do not perform GADT-like analysis on the argument.

How would such a mischievous GADT `Functor` instance look like? (Using only total functions of course, without `undefined`, `error` etc.)

Comment: What's wrong with `undefined` if it is not actually evaluated?

Comment: @n.m. If it's not evaluated, there should be a proof of it, for example that it's only evaluated when we get an instance of `Void` - then we can use `absurd` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: If evaluation of some expression terminates, this is enough of a proof that `undefined` was not evaluated in the process, isn't it?

Comment: @n.m. I'm seeking compile time proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible if you're willing to give a `Functor` instance that does not adhere to the functor laws (but is total):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Void
import Data.Void.Unsafe

data F :: * -> * where
  C :: F Void
  D :: F a

instance Functor F where
  fmap f _ = D

wrong :: ()
wrong = case (unsafeVacuous C :: F Int) of D -> ()
```

Now evaluating `wrong` results in a run-time exception, even though the type-checker considers it total.

#### Edit

Because there's been so much discussion about the functoriality, let me add an informal argument why a GADT that actually performs analysis on its argument cannot be a functor. If we have

```
data F :: * -> * where
  C :: ... -> F Something
  ...
```

where `Something` is any type that isn't a plain variable, then we cannot give a valid `Functor` instance for `F`. The `fmap` function would have to map `C` to `C` in order to adhere to the identity law for functors. But we have to produce an `F b`, for unknown `b`. If `Something` is anything but a plain variable, that isn't possible.

Comment: The documentation explicitly mentions "valid functor", so I assume it *has* to obey the functor laws. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis That's the point here, isn't it? The documentation says that `unsafeVacuous` is only safe for valid functors that don't do GADT analysis. The question was to demonstrate how the function can be unsafe as long as it's total. I think I demonstrated that.

Comment: I still don't see why people are highlighting the valid functor in the question and voting the comment up, to be honest. The documentation says that for valid functors, there's no problem, and I'm pretty sure that's true. Or do you claim the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: @kosmikus I upvoted your answer - it is helpful for me, and I also upvoted the comment. As I understand the documentation, it says that _it's safe for functors that are valid **and** don't perform GADT-like analysis_. So ideally I'd like to see a valid functor (adhering to the functor laws) that does use GADTs and this makes it fail with `unsafeVacuous`.

Comment: If you add the show instance `unsafeVacuous C :: F Int` evaluates to `C` instead of `D`, why?

Comment: @PetrPudlák But a valid functor cannot do GADT-analysis on the functor argument, independently of the question of safety of the `unsafeVacuous` function.

Comment: @is7s Because `unsafeVacuous` is implemented in terms of `unsafeCoerce`. It does not use `fmap`.